# Hibernate session factory not Autowired (Spring 4.2.4 and Tiles 3.0.5)

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles-3

I had a working Spring (4.2.4) & Hibernate/MySql project within which I have implemented Tiles (3.0.5). Now, when I run my project and follow the link to my "herp" view (which formally displayed a list of records returned by a database query) debugging shows that my Autowired SessionContext object is null; the latter is defined as a bean in my root context. Tiles/JSP for *static* pages is working as expected and my controllers are 'firing'. I'm new to all of these frameworks and following tutorials, so hopefully a stupid config error...? Thanks in advance.

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>herpWeb</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value> <!-- Anything related to web tier -->
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>tiles</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**root-context.xml**

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="uk.ac.open.my.dja389.herp" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/herp" />
    <property name="username" value="j2ee" />
    <property name="password" value="j2ee" />
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="uk.ac.open.my.dja389.herp.**.*" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="uk.ac.open.my.dja389.herp.controller" />

<!-- Used to serve static resources like css, images and javascript files -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/pages directory -->
<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs/templates.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**HerpController.java**

```
package uk.ac.open.my.dja389.herp.controller;

@Controller
public class HerpController {

private HerpBean herpBean;

@Autowired
private HerpService herpService;

@Autowired
private HerpRepository herpRepository;

public HerpController() {
    this.herpBean = new HerpBean();
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "/herp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView get() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("herp");
    model.addObject(this.herpBean);
    model.addObject("herpRepo", this.herpRepository);
    return model;
}

}
```

**HerpRepositoryImpl.java**

```
package uk.ac.open.my.dja389.herp.repositories;

@Repository("herpRepository")
public class HerpRepositoryImpl implements HerpRepository {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
@Transactional
public void save(Herp herp) {
    Session currentSession = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(herp);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Herp> getAllHerps() {

<<<debug here reports sessionFactory is null>>>

    List<Herp> allHerps = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Herp").list();
    return allHerps;
}

}
```

**Exception (excerpts)**

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is  
org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/pages/herp.jsp'.

java.lang.NullPointerException
uk.ac.open.my.dja389.herp.repositories.HerpRepositoryImpl.getAllHerps(HerpRepositoryImpl.java:29)
```

Comment: What if you call getAllHerps from the contoller ? Making business call in JSP is not a good thing, get all your data in your controller and then fill your model.

Comment: Thanks for the response/best practice advice. But making the call to .getAllHerps() from within the controller fails in the same way - the autowiring has not occurred and I still have no SessionFactory at the debug point indicated in the OP.